# ASP.NET-MVC - Website running total function not working

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

Trying to create a running total that will count calories for my website as part of a college assignment. Everything is finished apart from this one section which keeps on tripping me up. In theory it should take in a value and add it to a running total and display this total, but I think each time I press the button to calculate this it runs a new instance of the model I use to calculate this. There are 3 files interacting with each other for this operation

1. CalorieCount.cs - The model which contains the data and the calculation

   ```
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Web;
   using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

   namespace BlairMackenzie_CalorieCount.Models
   {
       public class CalorieCount
       {
           // Stores user input for calculating calorie count
           [Required]
           [Display(Name = "Calories Consumed")]
           public int CalorieIntake { get; set; }

           // Stores the running total
           [Display(Name = "Total Calories Consumed Today")]
           public int TotalCalorieCount { get; set; }

           // This method calculates total calorie count
           public void CalculateTotalCalorieCount()
           {
               // Add CalorieIntake to TotalCalorieCount
               TotalCalorieCount += CalorieIntake;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. CalorieCounter.cshtml - The webpage to display all this to the user and take an input

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CalorieCounter";
}

<h2>Calorie Counter</h2>
<br />
<hr />

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-lg">
            <tr>
                <!-- Displays label and input box for CalorieIntake -->
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.CalorieIntake)</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.CalorieIntake)</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <!-- Displays label and display for TotalCalorieCount -->
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.TotalCalorieCount)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TotalCalorieCount)</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <!-- Submit button triggers calculation -->
                    <input type="submit" value="Calculate New Total Calories" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

3. HomeController.cs - handles the loading the page and calling for the model to handle the calculations

```
        // Loads Calorie Count Page
        // Sets up empty form
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult CalorieCounter()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // This action is called when the user clicks the submit button
        // The completed form is sent to the back end
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CalorieCounter(CalorieCount model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                model.CalculateTotalCalorieCount();
            }
            return View(model); // Return the model to the view with all values calculated
        }
```

If anyone can spot this issue and suggest a fix that would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some fundamental misunderstandings going on here. ASP.NET MVC is essentially a "stateless" system. So when you make a request from the browser to the server, *everything* on the server is brand-new, uninitialised memory. It's "newing-up" all objects that are used to process the request and send a response.

So if you have a bit of data that you want to persist between requests, you have a couple of options:

1. Make sure all the data you need is "round-tripped" each time. That will often mean you need hidden `<input />` fields in your pages to contain that data, inside the form. As long as those inputs are setup correctly (I recommend using HtmlHelper, i.e. `Html.HiddenFor<T>()`) then the framework will match the value up and set that property of the model object in your POST handler.
2. Store data on the server, in a database. each request loads the current data, adds the new amount to it, and saves it, then displays whatever it needs to on the page.

### UPDATE

After making a working MVC site from your example and replicating the problem, I did some research and found that the HtmlHelpers look at ModelState before looking at the model that was passed to the view. This is why the value is never updating. I also noticed that there was a validation error because the `int TotalCalorieCount` implied a value was required, and presumably 0 wasn't good enough.

So here's what I did to get it working:

1. Add `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TotalCalorieCount)` immediately before the submit button in the view.
2. Make `CalorieCount.TotalCalorieCount` `int?` rather than `int` (which removed the DataAnnotations-implied requirement to be present.
3. Added a call to `ModelState.Clear()` immediately inside the `if (ModelState.IsValid)` block in `HomeController`.

It now works as you'd expect for me.

HomeController.cs

```
// Loads Calorie Count Page
// Sets up empty form
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CalorieCounter()
{
    return View();
}

// This action is called when the user clicks the submit button
// The completed form is sent to the back end
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CalorieCounter(CalorieCount model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ModelState.Clear();
        model.CalculateTotalCalorieCount();
    }
    return View(model); // Return the model to the view with all values calculated
}
```

CalorieCount.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class CalorieCount
    {
        // Stores user input for calculating calorie count
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Calories Consumed")]
        public int CalorieIntake { get; set; }

        // Stores the running total
        [Display(Name = "Total Calories Consumed Today")]
        public int? TotalCalorieCount { get; set; }

        // This method calculates total calorie count
        public void CalculateTotalCalorieCount()
        {
            // Add CalorieIntake to TotalCalorieCount
            TotalCalorieCount = (TotalCalorieCount ?? 0) + CalorieIntake;
        }
    }
}
```

CalorieCounter.cshtml

```
@model CalorieCount
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CalorieCounter";
}

<h2>Calorie Counter</h2>
<br />
<hr />

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-lg">
            <tr>
                <!-- Displays label and input box for CalorieIntake -->
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.CalorieIntake)</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.CalorieIntake)</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <!-- Displays label and display for TotalCalorieCount -->
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.TotalCalorieCount)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TotalCalorieCount)</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <!-- Submit button triggers calculation -->
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TotalCalorieCount)
                    <input type="submit" value="Calculate New Total Calories" class="btn btn-lg btn-success"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

One last thing. If you don't want to make `CalorieCount.TotalCalorieCount` a nullable int, you could return a model to your view in the GET, instead, like this:

```
// Loads Calorie Count Page
// Sets up empty form
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CalorieCounter()
{
    return View(new CalorieCount() { TotalCalorieCount = 0 });
}
```

Which also fixes that part of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, do you think you could show a quick example of what those hidden input fields might look like in my code, just not too sure how that works, but thanks for the advice.

Comment: It'll literally be the same as you've done for `EditorFor` in your code. Perhaps just near the submit button (so inside the form, of course, or it won't be submitted), put something like `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TotalCalorieCount)`. If you use `EditorFor`, ASP.NET MVC will choose an appropriate visible input control, but `HiddenFor` specifically creates an `<input type="hidden" ... />` in your html.

Comment: Unfortunately that hasn't worked, now the output is always 0, i think i should be able to make a database for it instead so hopefully that works

Comment: Have you checked what is in the HTML and that the names of properties and input controls match, etc? Is the hidden input inside the HTML form, so it gets submitted?

Comment: I've made an update. I basically replicated the situation and found the fixes for it so I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: ah, i hadn't changed the datatype for TotalCalorieCount so that'd probably be why it didn't work, i've handed in my project with the solution i found, but i'll definitely keep this in mind for future as it's probably better practice.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up fixing this issue by creating a DbSet for the CalorieCount model and had this store every calculation made. The controller would loop through this database until it found the largest id showing it was the newest calculation and it will store the TotalCalorieCount in a local variable and add the CalorieIntake and send the local variable to the model so it can be displayed by the webpage.

Comment: That was unnecessary. See my update to my answer.